# Why date.setMonth(10);date.setDate(20); gives me Dec 20 instead of Nov 20?

Tags: javascript

The following Javascript code

```
date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(2015);date.setMonth(10);date.setDate(20);
document.write(date);
document.write('<br/>');
date.setFullYear(2015);date.setDate(20);date.setMonth(10);
document.write(date);
```

gives me:

```
Sun Dec 20 2015 ...
Fri Nov 20 2015 ...
```

Why date.setMonth(10);date.setDate(20); gives me Dec 20 instead of Nov 20?

```js
date = new Date();
date.setFullYear(2015);date.setMonth(10);date.setDate(20);
document.write(date);
document.write('<br/>');
date.setFullYear(2015);date.setDate(20);date.setMonth(10);
document.write(date);
```

Comment: You can do it in one step:  `date.setFullYear(2015, 10, 20);`. Inserted your code as a snippet in the question, it doesn't produce the stated result.

Comment: reminded me of Java's strange calendar behavior: https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/gotcha-java-calendar-class-returns-0-based-month-but-1-based-days/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result I stated occurred on October 31. Therefore when the browser executes setMonth(10), it finds that November does not have 31 days and set the month to the next month that has 31 days (December).

The same result will occur when you setMonth(1), setMonth(3), setMonth(5), ... on the 31st day in a month or when you setMonth(1) on the 30th day.

Comment: "it finds that November does not have 31 days and set the month to the next month that has 31 days (December)." --- that's not entirely correct

Comment: yes it thinks 31st November is 1st December.  Fixing by setting day/date before the month won't work either if you try and set to 31st inside a month that doesn't have 31 days.  Only solution is date.setFullYear(2015,1,1) then set month then set date, or do all inside the first call

Answer (score -1):

Because javascript has a stupid implementation of [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setmonth.asp) with dates being 0-11 and not 1-12 like we think about them natural. Yet setDate is still 1-31... UGH!!!

Comment: It's not stupid if you have an array of month strings: `months = ["Jan", "Feb", ...];  return months[d.getMonth()];`